# Determining correct php-fpm max_children value against available RAM

Tags: php, linux, memory, system-administration

I'm trying to benchmark and figure out the correct PHP-FPM `pm.max_children` settings.

I'm using the following formula to work out the average size of a PHP-FPM process:

```
ps -ylC php-fpm --sort:rss | awk '{sum+=$8; ++n} END {print "Tot="sum"("n")";print "Avg="sum"/"n"="sum/n/1024"MB"}'
```

This returns me 31MB. I've only got about 2GB to play with on the system in question - so theorotically if I change `pm.max_children` inside the PHP-FPM config file to be 2048MB / 31MB = 66.

I then used `ab` to benchmark it - I quickly hit the `pm.max_children` limit (`[06-Oct-2021 10:32:37] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (66), consider raising it`) but I can see I've got plenty of memory to spare.

When checking with free:

```
# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1954         914         756          15         284         869
Swap:             0           0           0
```

So then I `pm.max_children` to 200 - to test further and again hit the limit:

```
[06-Oct-2021 10:34:46] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (200), consider raising it
```

Memory usage via free is lower but still not what I'd expect based on the calculation:

```
# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1954        1595          74          15         285         188
Swap:             0           0           0
```

Going off the calculation above, if each process was using 31MB as shown in the RSS column:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
apache   17558  0.3  1.5 859324 31820 ?        R    10:16   0:02 php-fpm: pool www
apache   17577  0.3  1.5 859468 31848 ?        R    10:16   0:02 php-fpm: pool www
apache   17603  0.3  1.5 859464 31836 ?        R    10:16   0:02 php-fpm: pool www
```

The number of PHP-FPM processes is:

```
ps aux | grep php-fpm | grep -v grep | wc -l
```

= 200

And if I multiply the value in RSS (which is average 31000KB) * 200 = ~ 6GB memory.

However if I use the `ps_mem.py` utility, the overall usage of PHP-FPM is a lot lower:

```
882.4 MiB +  26.9 MiB = 909.4 MiB   php-fpm (201)
```

What am I missing here in terms of working out the correct value?

It seems as though the advice to utilise available memory / average php-fpm process memory (as calculated by the `ps` command above) gives inconsistent results..

---

For reference here are some articles recommending this method to calculate `pm.max_children`:

- https://gist.github.com/holmberd/44fa5c2555139a1a46e01434d3aaa512
- https://chrismoore.ca/2018/10/finding-the-correct-pm-max-children-settings-for-php-fpm/

Comment: Did you get your issue fixed? We've got in to this problem now! If you've fixed it, kindly share us the solution.

Comment: Unfortunatenly I did not - I utilised a monitoring tool to keep a close eye on the memory utilisation of the VM in question but have yet to find a good answer.